# Looking to make guns from reference on Blender, don't know where to start

Tags: modeling

I was wondering where one'd start trying to do hard surface modelling on Blender. I understand that there are many tutorials out there which I appreciate, I've done the doughnut one by Blender Guru, but I'm still not sure how I can create hard, clean models close to realism, thanks

Comment: I say try taking a reference image of a gun and just try and block it out and make a low poly version, then just try and refine it and subdivide until you get it to the quality you want.

Comment: That's obvious, but keep in mind I'm fairly new so I still can't subdivide to perfection

Comment: Hi and welcome. Not sure what answer you expect here. Where *exactly* do you have problems? Hard surface modeling techniques are perfect for guns, that's right. Use a reference image as Nascent Space recommended. Blenderguru has an Anvil tutorial that is worth following along. Grant Abbitt has also some great, free, and beginner-friendly tutorial series about hard surface modeling. They cover the use of the modifiers (Bevel, Shrinkwrap, etc). If you have a *specific* problem then edit your question and ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question, but this tutorial by Blender Guru on YouTube will help you out with learning great modeling techniques that can be used for making weapons.  It shows how to set up reference images and plan the building process. The tutorial shows how to build a chair and has 9 parts.  All parts can be applied to what you need.  I learned from this guy and now able to build many things.  Hope this helps.  https://youtu.be/Hf2esGA7vCc